# How to find kth smallest value of a linear equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Here's a question that was asked in IOITC 2009 India. Even though it should have a solution related to algorithms, yet I post it here as it is pretty "number-theoretic".

> Indraneel loves posing number theoretic problems. Here is one for you from his collection:
>
> Given two integers a, b > 0 and an integer K your task is to determine the Kth smallest number that can be expressed as *x·a + y·b* for some pair of integers x,y > 0. For instance, if a=2 and b = 4 and K = 4 the answer is 12.
>
> In all tests, 1 ≤ a,b ≤ 10^12 and 1 ≤ K ≤ 10^5

Me and a friend of min have been trying to solve this problem since atleast a day, and haven't made much head way on the solution. The greedy strategy can't work, and trying to brute force the solution is not a good idea here due to the limits...
Any ideas for solving the problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely algorithmic perspective, a priority-first search should work fine for the parameters given; it's logarithmic in $a$ and $b$, and roughly linear in $k$ (depending on your implementation).

At stage $k$, this algorithm produces the $k$-th smallest expressible number; it also maintains a list $C$ of "candidates" as a priority queue.  Initially $C=\{a,b\}$; at the $k$-th stage, the smallest element $x$ of $C$ is guaranteed to be the $k$-th smallest expressible number; remove it from $C$ and insert both $x+a$ and $x+b$ into $C$.  The size of $C$ after $k$ steps is at most $2k$, so if you implement the priority queue as a binary heap, the entire algorithm takes $O(k\lg k)$ operations on integers of size at most $k\max(a,b)$.  This is essentially just Dijkstra's algorithm on the directed graph with edges from $x$ to $x+a$ and $x+b$ for any $x$.

(If the intent is that both $x$ and $y$ need to be positive, you initialize $C$ to $\{a+b\}$ instead.)

An algorithm which is sublinear in $k$ would certainly be more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

An approach :

A number $n$ can be representated by $xa+yb$ with integers $x,y$ (not necessarily positive!) if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $g:=gcd(a,b)$

We can assume $gcd(a,b)=1$ because if $gcd(a,b)=g$ we can set
$a'=\frac{a}{g}$, $b'=\frac{b}{g}$ and $n$ can be represented
by $xa'+yb'$ if and only if $ng$ can be represented by $xa+xb$.
In other words, the numbers which can be represented by
$xa+xb$ are the numbers which can be represented by $xa'+yb'$,
multiplied with $g$.

Under this assumption,the equation $ua+vb=1$ always has a solution.

Then, $$(tb+nu)a + (nv-ta)b = tab + nua + nvb - tab = n(ua+vb)=n$$

It can be shown that the general solution for $xa+yb=n$ is

$x=tb+nu$ and $y=nv-ta$

Now, we have to check, for which $n$ there is a solution with $x,y>0$

This gives $-\frac{nu}{b}<t<\frac{nv}{a}$. For each $n$, check
if such an integer $t$ exists.

Example : $a=3,b=5$ We can choose $u=2,v=-1$.
It turns out that for every $s\ge16$ and $s=8,11,13,14$ there is a solution.

So, the numbers $8,11,13,14,16,17,18,19,...$ can be represented in the desired way.